# manipulation of subtraction

Tags: induction, fractions

I am trying to solve an induction problem and got stuck at this part.

$$ 1 - \frac{n+2}{(n+2)!} + \frac{n+1}{(n+2)!} = 1 - \frac{(n+2) - (n+1)}{(n+2)!} $$

Shouldn't it be

$$ 1 - \frac{n+2}{(n+2)!} + \frac{n+1}{(n+2)!} = 1 - \frac{(n+2) + (n+1)}{(n+2)!} $$

How do you get the left expression to the right expression?

Comment: $$1 - x + y = 1 - (x-y).$$

Comment: Calculate $7-6+5$. Do you get the same thing as $7-(6+5)$, or the same thing as $7-(6-5)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yeah I understand that, but what are the "rules" when dealing with fractions instead?

Comment: The rules are the same, no matter what you are dealing with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you feel more comfortable with this?

$$1-\dfrac{n+2}{(n+2)!}+\dfrac{n+1}{(n+2)!}=1+\dfrac{(n+1)-(n+2)}{(n+2)!}$$

If you chose to, you could rewrite it from here to

$$1-[-\dfrac{(n+1)-(n+2)}{(n+2)!}]=1-\dfrac{(n+2)-(n+1)}{(n+2)!}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that 
$$-\frac{A+B}{C}=(-1)\times \left(\frac{A+B}{C}\right)=(-1)\times\left(\frac{A}{C}+\frac{B}{C}\right)=-\frac{A}{C}-\frac{B}{C}=\frac{-A-B}{C}.$$

The minus sign in front of the first fraction does influence the plus sign in front of $B$ of the numerator of the first fraction.

Comment: And then $$ \frac{-A - B}{C} = - \frac{A - B}{C}    ? $$

Comment: NO. it is $$-\frac{A+B}{C}.$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this then?

$$ 1 - \frac{n+2}{(n+2)!} + \frac{n+1}{(n+2)!} = 1 - \frac{-(n+2) - (n+1)}{(n+2)!} $$

Comment: NO. notice that the sign in front of the fraction influences the signs in the numerator.